# app crashing when trying to set a NSUserDefault with button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I'm creating an app and trying to update a NSUserDefault from a a different view controller, although i don't think its the separate view controller thats doing it because i can't set a new NSUserDefault on this controller either. its crashing whenever i push the button, heres the code from the view controller:

```
//  Upgrades.swift
//  Unit3Final
//
//  Created by fgstu on 4/14/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 AllenH. All rights reserved.
//

    import UIKit

    class Upgrades: UIViewController {


    var tapModifier = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("tapModifier"))


    func storeTheScore() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(tapModifier, forKey: "tapModifier")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func BuyAHut(sender: UIButton) {

        tapModifier += 5

        storeTheScore()

    }



}
```

it is set in my main view controller in my viewDidLoad with

```
var tapModifier: Int = 1
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(tapModifier, forKey: "tapModifier")
```

and the error message is

```
2016-04-14 12:13:45.264 Unit3Final[40985:5120078] -[Unit3Final.Upgrades hutUpgrade:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fadab4b2e80
2016-04-14 12:13:45.270 Unit3Final[40985:5120078] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Unit3Final.Upgrades hutUpgrade:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fadab4b2e80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010258de65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001042cddeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010259648d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024e390a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024e34b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000102dac194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000102f1b6fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000102f1b9c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000102f1aaf8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000102e1b49b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000102e1c1d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000102dcab66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000102da4d97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024b9a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024af95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024aee13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024ae828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000106bcdad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000102daa610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  Unit3Final                          0x000000010201db7d main + 109
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000104ddf92d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Where is the program crashing ? What's the crash message ? Please don't just dump your code for us to debug. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, edited it and added the message

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a value, that's why it's crashing, try setting it to 0 initially.

You're adding 5 to nothing, instead of this,

```
tapModifier = NSUserDefaults etc...
```

try...

```
tapModifier = 0
```